# parse_date_time() converting DayofYear in date

Tags: r, lubridate

Hi I'm using the lubridate package and
I want to convert a vector from 1:365 (day of year) in a date format:

e.g. **60** -> **2019-03-01 UTC**.

For 1-99 it works fine, but for 100-365 I get a warning massage.

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time(99, "j")
[1] "2019-04-09 UTC"

lubridate::parse_date_time(100:365, "j")
[1] NA ...
[365] NA

Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Gets anyone the same warning massage or has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide character input, it works well

```
lubridate::parse_date_time('100', "j")
# [1] "2019-04-10 UTC"
lubridate::parse_date_time(paste(100:365), "j")
# [1] "2019-04-10 UTC" "2019-04-11 UTC" "2019-04-12 UTC" "2019-04-13 UTC" "2019-04-14 UTC" "2019-04-15 UTC" "2019-04-16 UTC" "2019-04-17 UTC"
# ...
# [265] "2019-12-30 UTC" "2019-12-31 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. But it is still strange that it doesn't works for numeric >= 100.

Comment: function argument is a character or numeric vector of dates. My guess is if it's more than 3 symbols, function can't recognize input format.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do it with specifying origin date using

> `as.Date(100:365, format = "%j", origin = "01-01-2019")`

Comment: Thanks, but keep in mind that it starts counting with 0, you have to subtract 1